# Incompatible shapes in Keras when loading a model with custom layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to implement a Subpixel upconvolution layer in Keras. I can train a model without a problem and save it. But I cannot load that model back. I always get an error of the dimensions being wrong.

The only way it works is if I save the weights, create a new model and then load the weights. But this isn't ideal, though, since the optimizer resets so it's hard to resume training.

```py
import keras
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

class Subpixel(keras.layers.Conv2D):

    def __init__(self,
                 filters,
                 kernel_size,
                 scale,
                 padding='valid',
                 data_format='channels_last',
                 strides=(1, 1),
                 activation=None,
                 use_bias=True,
                 kernel_initializer='he_normal',
                 bias_initializer='zeros',
                 kernel_regularizer=None,
                 bias_regularizer=None,
                 activity_regularizer=None,
                 kernel_constraint=None,
                 bias_constraint=None,
                 **kwargs):
        super().__init__(
            filters=scale * scale * filters,
            kernel_size=kernel_size,
            strides=strides,
            padding=padding,
            data_format=data_format,
            activation=activation,
            use_bias=use_bias,
            kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer,
            bias_initializer=bias_initializer,
            kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer,
            bias_regularizer=bias_regularizer,
            activity_regularizer=activity_regularizer,
            kernel_constraint=kernel_constraint,
            bias_constraint=bias_constraint,
            **kwargs)
        self.scale = scale
        self.data_format = data_format

    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.depth_to_space(super().call(inputs), self.scale)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        if self.data_format == 'channels_first':
            b, k, r, c = super().compute_output_shape(input_shape)
            return b, k // (self.scale ** 2), r * self.scale, c * self.scale
        else:
            b, r, c, k = super().compute_output_shape(input_shape)
            return b, r * self.scale, c * self.scale, k // (self.scale ** 2)

    def get_config(self):
        config = super(keras.layers.Conv2D, self).get_config()
        config['filters'] = int(config['filters'] / self.scale * self.scale)
        config['scale'] = self.scale
        return config

X = np.random.rand(100, 2, 2, 1)
y = np.random.rand(100, 4, 4, 1)

inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=(2, 2, 1))
x = Subpixel(4, 4, 2, padding='same')(inputs)
output = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs, output)
model.compile(optimizer='sgd',
                          loss='mean_absolute_error',
                          metrics=[])

model.fit(X, y)
model.save('foo.h5')
foo = keras.models.load_model('foo.h5', custom_objects={'Subpixel': Subpixel})
```

It appears that the conflict is between the shape in the weight file and the architecture that is loaded in. The kernel shape is incorrect on the loaded model. It is 4,4,1,64 when it should be 4,4,1,16. The output is as follows:

```py
self = TensorShape([Dimension(4), Dimension(4), Dimension(1), Dimension(64)])
other = TensorShape([Dimension(4), Dimension(4), Dimension(1), Dimension(16)])

    def assert_is_compatible_with(self, other):
      """Raises exception if `self` and `other` do not represent the same shape.

      This method can be used to assert that there exists a shape that both
      `self` and `other` represent.

      Args:
        other: Another TensorShape.

      Raises:
        ValueError: If `self` and `other` do not represent the same shape.
      """
      if not self.is_compatible_with(other):
>       raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))
E       ValueError: Shapes (4, 4, 1, 64) and (4, 4, 1, 16) are incompatible
```

Answer (score 2):

Extremely stupid mistake. The line:

```
config['filters'] = int(config['filters'] / self.scale * self.scale)
```

Should be:

```
config['filters'] = int(config['filters'] / (self.scale * self.scale))
```

Otherwise when serializing the layer, the wrong input parameter for filters is saved. Basically I got mixed up by operator precedence.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error but it was not caused by a mistake or typo. Instead, I encountered a bug in TensorFlow and managed to solve it by uninstalling the tensorflow package before reinstalling the newest version.

Thus,

```
pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu
pip uninstall tensorflow-cpu
pip uninstall tensorflow
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

did the trick for me.